# jqueryUI datepicker - altfield hiding?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

So I know one can do [this](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#alt-field).

But what I need is to essentially have one field(datepicker), when the user selects I show the date in user friendly format, but in the code I pass computer friendly date. I was thinking of hiding the datepicker, but how would the user make a selection then? Are my options limited to the demo linked?

Another option is to do a conversion behind the scenes, but I am trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the DatePicker's current date via the API call to [getDate()](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate). It will give you the selected date in a Date format so you can then format it the way you want it (computer friendly date).